# Using BlueStacks with Appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, appcelerator, bluestacks, appcelerator-studio

How do I emulate Android apps built in titanium through BlueStacks app player ?

The Android emulators are taking so long to build and rum the app.

I don't want to use Android device for debugging app. Are there any other alternative ? Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [NoxPlayer](https://www.bignox.com) with debugging feature in android studio, It's free and very fast!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Genymotion** emulator in the Accelerator Studio.

Here you go:http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Genymotion

BTW, BlueStacks is not supported by Appcelerator Studio.